# How to allow copy action in TextViewer without keybinding?

Tags: swt, jface, key-bindings

I am using a `TextViewer` and by default, I am getting SWT context menus Copy and Select All. Is there a way to remove the keybinding from the actions?

Special case:  I need this because the key binding clashes with the keybinding I have in my master tree.

I don't want the user to use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> for the `TextViewer` and use only context menu right click 'Copy'.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost: you should not try to disable common functionality provided by the platform.

Application software builds upon a platform for a reason: to provide a consistent interface for user interactions common across applications.

If you still want to disable certain key binding, you can use `StyledText::addKeyVerifyListener` or Display::addFilter()` to intercept key strokes and prevent the corresponding event from being processed.

For example:

```java
StyledText styledText = textViewer.getTextWidget();
styledText.addVerifyKeyListener( new VerifyKeyListener() {
  @Override
  public void verifyKey( VerifyEvent event ) {
    if( event.character == 'c' && ( event.stateMask & SWT.CTRL ) != 0 ) {
      event.doit = false;
    }
  }
} );
```